# How can I select multiple folders with JavaFX using DirectoryChooser?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm using the latest version of JavaFX and I'm trying to open a user dialog to select multiple folders at once. I know you can do it in Swing but I'm trying to do it in JavaFX. I tried using DirectoryChooser but as far as I can see there is no method that allows you to choose multiple directories. Does anyone know how I can go about this or should I just use Swing?

Comment: JavaFX directory chooser does not support selecting multiple directories as some mobile platforms (or Linux native dialogues) does not support selecting multiple directories and they want selection to be consistent across platforms. I read this somewhere can't find it now :(